# Having trouble with a while loop in bash script

Tags: bash, loops, awk, while-loop, scripting

I'm trying to get the variables setup properly in my script. Basically the x and y variables should increment by 5 after each iteration of the loop. The a value should increment by one, and the loop should iterate $numResults amount of times.

The numResults variable is working fine and the loop does try to iterate that number of times. I'm encountering 4 sets of errors since that's the number stored in that variable. For my other variables, when I replace them with real numbers, then the program runs fine but just not with the variables in place.

```
    #!/bin/bash

# An application that for each course with more than 50 students enrolled generates 
# an advisory report to warn of over-enrollment. It generates a text file from a user-defined 
# template which uses the following variables:
# 
# • [[dept_code]]
# • [[dept_name]]
# • [[course_name]]
# • [[course_start]]
# • [[course_end]]
# • [[credit_hours]]
# • [[num_students]]
# • [[course_num]] (the course number as specified in the filename of the .crs file)
# • [[date]]
#
# Create a new user-specified subdirectory for files
mkdir -p "$4"

numResults=$(grep -rE --include \*.crs -e "^[5][1-9]$" -e "^[6-9][0-9]$" -e "^[1-9][0-9][0-9]$" "$1" | gawk '{n++} END { print n }')

let i=0;
x=1
y=5
a=1
while [[ $i<="$numResults" ]]
do
# Gets the course code and number to use as the output file name && stores course_num to the output file temporarily for retrieval
file=$(grep -rE --include \*.crs -e "^[5][1-9]$" -e "^[6-9][0-9]$" -e "^[1-9][0-9][0-9]$" "$1" | sed -E 's/.*([A-Z]{3})([0-9]{4})\.*crs:[0-9][0-9]/\1\2/g' | gawk 'NR==$a { print; echo "" }')
course=$(echo $file | sed 's/[A-Z]//g')
(cat "$2"; echo ""; echo "$course";) > "$4/$file"


# Locate all files in the data directory with the .crs extension that also contain a line with 
# only a string "51" - "999" and grabs the contents of that file and stores them to the new 
# output file temporarily for retrieval
grep -hrEB 4 --include \*.crs -e "^[5][1-9]$" -e "^[6-9][0-9]$" -e "^[1-9][0-9][0-9]$" "$1" | gawk 'NR==$x,NR==$y{print}' >> "$4"/$file


# Create variables to hold the dept and course info
varCNum=$(gawk -v n=6 '{saved[FNR % n] = $0} ENDFILE {if (FNR >= n) print saved[(FNR + 1) % n]}' "$4"/$file)

varDC=$(gawk -v n=5 '{saved[FNR % n] = $1} ENDFILE {if (FNR >= n) print saved[(FNR + 1) % n]}' "$4"/$file)
varDN=$(gawk -v n=5 '{saved[FNR % n] = $0} ENDFILE {if (FNR >= n) print saved[(FNR + 1) % n]}' "$4"/$file | gawk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s", $i};}')

varCN=$(gawk -v n=4 '{saved[FNR % n] = $0} ENDFILE {if (FNR >= n) print saved[(FNR + 1) % n]}' "$4"/$file)
varCS=$(gawk -v n=3 '{saved[FNR % n] = $2} ENDFILE {if (FNR >= n) print saved[(FNR + 1) % n]}' "$4"/$file)
varCE=$(gawk -v n=3 '{saved[FNR % n] = $3} ENDFILE {if (FNR >= n) print saved[(FNR + 1) % n]}' "$4"/$file)
varCH=$(gawk -v n=2 '{saved[FNR % n] = $0} ENDFILE {if (FNR >= n) print saved[(FNR + 1) % n]}' "$4"/$file)

varNS=$(gawk -v n=1 '{saved[FNR % n] = $0} ENDFILE {if (FNR >= n) print saved[(FNR + 1) % n]}' "$4"/$file)


# Substitute the variables into the output file && and clean up
sed -E "s/\[\[ dept_code \]\]/$varDC/g; s/\[\[ dept_name \]\]/$varDN/g; 
s@\[\[ course_name \]\]@$varCN@g; s@\[\[ course_start \]\]@$varCS@g; s@\[\[ course_end \]\]@$varCE@g;
s@\[\[ credit_hours \]\]@$varCH@g; s@\[\[ num_students \]\]@$varNS@g; 
s@\[\[ course_num \]\]@$varCNum@g; s@\[\[ date \]\]@$varDate@g;" "$4"/$file | sed -e :a -e '$d;N;2,6ba' -e 'P;D'

let i+=1
let x+=5
let y+=5
let a+=1

done
```

I'm passing in the following arguments to my script:
    $ ./assign4.sh ./data assign4.template 12/16/2021 ./output

```
Which gives the following error message "./assign4.sh: line 31: ./output: Is a directory
./assign4.sh: line 37: ./output: Is a directory
gawk: warning: command line argument `./output' is a directory: skipped"
```

Comment: You should avoid in bash using old and deprecated back-tics.  Use parentheses in stead like this `numResults=$(grep -rE --include .....)`

Comment: Apart from what Jotne mentioned. IMHO your question is not clear, please keep your question simple by editing only needful details in it, kindly do edit it and let us know.

Comment: I'm thinking I may just have a syntax error: 'NR==$a. Is that the way to print the number of record, starting with the first one, and then later in the code let a+=1 so the loop can run again and the next time it will print NR==2 and store it in the $file variable?

Comment: @duckyPluck, please check your arguments once looks like they are not properly passed? Or you try to pass a file name with its absolute path to ot once? Lemme know how it goes then.

Comment: I was forgetting the date when passing in the arguments. Now the error is ./output/: is a directory , instead of /: . So it is recognizing it as my 4th argument at least.

Comment: When I replace the x, y variables in the script with 1, 5 and replace 'a' with 1, the script runs ok, just with the same information printing out 4 times.

Comment: @duckyPluck, Though I am not fully sure as it is NOT clear what arguments exactly you are passing. Try once `./assign4.sh "/your_complete_path/data assign4.template" "12/16/2021" "/your_complete_path/output"` and lemme know?

Comment: Is gawk 'NR==$a { print; echo "" }' proper syntax? Because my script runs fine expect for when I have the variable there. If I substitute a '1' in place of '$a', for example, it runs but just not as intended.

Comment: @duckyPluck, No shell variables doesn't work in awk by this way, something like this `gawk -v var="$a" 'NR==var {print}' Input_file` should work. Where `a="shell_variable"` is shell variable.

Comment: Aaaah, I see. Silly me, I thought it would be able to see the shell variables in awk. That makes perfect sense now though,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your requirement is not fully clear, by seeing your error looks like you may need to pass full path of your directories/files where you want to capture output etc.

```
./assign4.sh "/your_complete_path/data assign4.template" "12/16/2021" "/your_complete_path/output"
```

I am also wrapping arguments in `"` to avoid any confusions in case your directory name has any spaces in their names, it will avoid it then.